# How to filter JSON Response in Telegraf

Tags: json, telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin

I am trying to ingest JSON metric data from HTTP-Endpoints using Telegraf's [HTTP Input Plugin](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/http), and write it to a Postgresql database using the [Postgresql Output plugin](https://github.com/svenklemm/telegraf/tree/postgres). This is working as expected.

However, some of the JSON-Responses are very long . Since the PostgreSQL Output plugin creates a column for every field, these tables become very long and cluttered with information I don't need.

For those endpoints where the data cannot be altered at the sender's side (For example: RabbitMQ's Premade API), is there a way to filter the JSON Response in Telegraf?

For example: I have the following JSON-Response:

```
{
    "message_stats": {
        "publish": 1,
        "publish_details": {
            "rate": 0.0
        }
    }
}
```

I am only interested in `message_stats.publish_details.rate`. I do not want `message_stats.publish` to appear in my database. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

One of the way how to solve this issue is using `json_query` parameter. 
In this parameter, you can use special syntax for filtering the response:

```
    [[inputs.http]]
  ## One or more URLs from which to read formatted metrics
  urls = [
    "https://url-to-metrics-endpoint"
  ]
  # next field replace default metrics name "http" to your custom name:
  name_override = "custom_name"
  # set true if you want to ignore self signed certificate validation:
  insecure_skip_verify = true 
  data_format = "json"
  timeout = "5s"
  # Here you can filter your JSON using special syntax:
  json_query = "message_stats.publish_details.rate"
```

This is easiest example. More details about syntax you can find here (for example how to work with arrays and a much more):
https://github.com/tidwall/gjson#path-syntax